# Rich Text column - How to add HTML Template

Tags: 2013, rich-text

I must add a HTML Template to reach Text Column, and it schould be Visible always. How Could I done it ? Only to give a template rich text to html, that nowan schould edit it

Comment: To clarify, are you looking for a rich text field on a list to have an HTML template within in it, and the user would update the content in context to the HTML template. The user should not be able to modify the template however. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, I making a Newsletter, on anousment list, and must prepere a template for Content, to sending as allerts this news. Or meyby David You know any component for Newsletter. but i try by Anocement List.

Comment: What version of SharePoint?

Comment: Sharepoint 2013 David

Answer (score 1):

You could use an announcements list to gather the data, and then use a workflow to format the data and send the email.

Using an HTML Template in a rich text field will require some custom code, should be possible via JavaScript, or maybe a 3rd party solution is available. I prefer the above idea using a list to collect many data points as you can use that as metadata for later filtering/reporting.

Comment: But how format data on workflow ? Or Have add a javaScript to column, or via Infopath to rich text ?

Comment: In the SPD Workflow, you can create a Send Mail action, and write the HTML and inserting the field values.

Comment: Creating a JS solution is too large for this thread. Briefly, you would inject the HTML into the rich text field. Making it locked down to not edit the template itself might be difficult, not sure off the top of my head.